# JQuery age verification method causing error undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, function, undefined, verification

Undefined is not a function was appearing on load of the document when i had $("body).on('change') ....

I changed the syntax to jQuery("body").on('change') and the undefined went away on load.....  now it throws the error on change of the event... what other bit of syntax could i possibly change to fix this problem?

```
jQuery("body").on('change', "#signup_form", function(event){

var day = $("#field_7_day").val();
var month = $("#field_7_month").val();
var year = $("#field_7_year").val();
var age = 18;
var mydate = new Date();
mydate.setFullYear(year, month-1, day);

var currdate = new Date();
currdate.setFullYear(currdate.getFullYear() - age);
if ((currdate - mydate) < 0){
    alert("Sorry, only persons over the age of " + age + " may enter this site");
    return false;
}
return true;   
});
```

html

```
<form action="" name="signup_form" id="signup_form" class="standard-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="register-section" id="profile-details-section">
     <h4>Profile Details</h4>
<div class="editfield">
  <div class="datebox">
   <label class="label-form required" for="field_7_day">Birthday (required)</label>
    <select name="field_7_day" id="field_7_day" aria-required="true">
     <option value="">--</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="27">27</option>
    </select>
    <select name="field_7_month" id="field_7_month" aria-required="true">
     <option value="">------</option>
     <option value="January">January</option>
     <option value="February">February</option>
     <option value="March">March</option>
    </select>
<select name="field_7_year" id="field_7_year" aria-required="true" required="required">
     <option value="">----</option>
     <option value="2013">2013</option>
     <option value="2012">2012</option>
</select>       
    </div>

<div class="field-visibility-settings" id="field-visibility-settings-7" style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="signup_profile_field_ids" id="signup_profile_field_ids" value="1,7,30,2,5,6,26">
</div><!-- #profile-details-section -->
<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" name="signup_submit" id="signup_submit" value="Complete Sign Up">
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="da99d8eeb9"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/register/">
```

I removed some of the options if thats not obvious so it didnt clutter up the page, this is just a piece of the overall form...

I would love to be able to do this verification once all 3 of the select boxes have been chosen prior to submitting... Something like an on event change if anyone could point me in the right direction to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the form change event...

```
$(document).on('submit', "#signup_form", function(event){
    ....
});
```

You can experiment using jsfiddle.net to make it all work by the way.

Here is a jsfiddle mock-up of your code... you can experiment, but it is working here. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/xyq75znv/5/

Comment: my problem is that its spitting this: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
(anonymous function)

Comment: Are you including jQuery in the head section of the document?

Comment: Undefined is not a function was appearing on load of the document when i had $("body).on('change') ....

 I changed the syntax to jQuery("body").on('change') and the undefined went away on load.....  now it throws the error on change of the event... what other bit of syntax could i possibly change to fix this problem?

Comment: i updated the above html to use  the on change event handler you suggested.. it appears to be working but as i said its still throwing this Undefined is not a function error on the change of the event...

Comment: Like I said above, use the fiddle editor to experiment and get what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/xyq75znv/3/

Comment: thank you! its at least validating correctly and throwing the OK at me but the age validation isnt working, did you have it working?

Comment: Here is a fully working version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/xyq75znv/5/

The months should be numeric values.

Comment: undefined is not a function kept appearing- the answer to that was to remove all of the $() and replace with jQuery()...  <3 thank you!

Comment: I generally do that to separate jQuery namespace. I am assuming you are working under Drupal or Wordpress correct? The namespace is jQuery rather than $. Glad this all worked out for you!